# Better examples of Parallel processing in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I hope I am not downvoted this time. I have been struggling with parallel processing in Python for a while(2 days , exactly). I have checking these resources(a partial list is shown here:

(a) http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/01/16/python-paralellizing-cpu-bound-tasks-with-concurrent-futures

(b) https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/tag/processpoolexecutor/

I came unstuck. What I want to do is this:

Master:

```
Break up the file into chunks(strings or numbers)
Broadcast a pattern to be searched to all the workers
Receive the offsets in the file where the pattern was found
```

Workers:

```
Receive pattern and chunk of text from the master
Compute()
Send back the offsets to the master.
```

I tried to implement this using MPI/concurrent.futures/multiprocessing and came unstuck.

My naive implementation using multiprocessing module

```
import multiprocessing

filename = "file1.txt"
pat = "afow"
N = 1000

""" This is the naive string search algorithm"""

def search(pat, txt):

    patLen = len(pat)
    txtLen = len(txt)
    offsets = []

    # A loop to slide pattern[] one by one
    # Range generates numbers up to but not including that number
    for i in range ((txtLen - patLen) + 1):

    # Can not use a for loop here
    # For loops in C with && statements must be
    # converted to while statements in python
        counter = 0
        while(counter < patLen) and pat[counter] == txt[counter + i]:
           counter += 1
           if counter >= patLen:
               offsets.append(i)
        return str(offsets).strip('[]')

       """"
       This is what I want 
if __name__ == "__main__":
     tasks = []
     pool_outputs = []
     pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
     with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
           lines = []
           for line in infile:
                lines.append(line.rstrip())
                if len(lines) > N:
                     pool_output = pool.map(search, tasks)
                     pool_outputs.append(pool_output)
                     lines = []
                if len(lines) > 0:
                     pool_output = pool.map(search, tasks)
                     pool_outputs.append(pool_output)
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
     print('Pool:', pool_outputs)
         """""

with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(search(pat, line))
```

I would be grateful for any guidance especially with the concurrent.futures. Thanks for your time. Valeriy helped me with his addition and I thank him for that.

But if anyone could just indulge me for a moment, this is the code I was working on for the concurrent.futures(working off an example I saw somewhere)

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
import math

def search(pat, txt):

    patLen = len(pat)
    txtLen = len(txt)
    offsets = []

# A loop to slide pattern[] one by one
# Range generates numbers up to but not including that number
    for i in range ((txtLen - patLen) + 1):

    # Can not use a for loop here
    # For loops in C with && statements must be
    # converted to while statements in python
        counter = 0
        while(counter < patLen) and pat[counter] == txt[counter + i]:
            counter += 1
            if counter >= patLen:
                offsets.append(i)
return str(offsets).strip('[]')

#Check a list of strings
def chunked_worker(lines):
    return {0: search("fmo", line) for line in lines}


def pool_bruteforce(filename, nprocs):
    lines = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    chunksize = int(math.ceil(len(lines) / float(nprocs)))
    futures = []

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for i in range(nprocs):
            chunk = lines[(chunksize * i): (chunksize * (i + 1))]
            futures.append(executor.submit(chunked_worker, chunk))

    resultdict = {}
    for f in as_completed(futures):
        resultdict.update(f.result())
    return resultdict


filename = "file1.txt"
pool_bruteforce(filename, 5)
```

Thanks again , Valeriy and anyone who attempts to help me solve my riddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using several arguments, so:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial
filename = "file1.txt"
pat = "afow"
N = 1000

""" This is the naive string search algorithm"""

def search(pat, txt):
    patLen = len(pat)
    txtLen = len(txt)
    offsets = []

    # A loop to slide pattern[] one by one
    # Range generates numbers up to but not including that number
    for i in range ((txtLen - patLen) + 1):

    # Can not use a for loop here
    # For loops in C with && statements must be
    # converted to while statements in python
        counter = 0
        while(counter < patLen) and pat[counter] == txt[counter + i]:
           counter += 1
           if counter >= patLen:
               offsets.append(i)
        return str(offsets).strip('[]')


if __name__ == "__main__":
     tasks = []
     pool_outputs = []
     pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
     lines = []
     with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
         for line in infile:
             lines.append(line.rstrip())                 
     tasks = lines
     func = partial(search, pat)
     if len(lines) > N:
        pool_output = pool.map(func, lines )
        pool_outputs.append(pool_output)     
     elif len(lines) > 0:
        pool_output = pool.map(func, lines )
        pool_outputs.append(pool_output)
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
     print('Pool:', pool_outputs)
```

Comment: Valeriy: Thanks. What does the partial do anyway? Do you know of any resources that thoroughly tackle parallel processing in python? Thanks again.

Comment: Valeriy: I have read that and could not really understand it. I am sorry but I meant as a proper example in a function. Thanks.